# Empty string is returned when using parse_str()

Tags: php

This is my string that I need to work with parse_str:

```
type%3Dbasic%26WhatPropType%3DSingle%2BFamily%2BResidential%26WhatDistrict%255B0%255D%3DHaiku%26WhatStartPrice%3D90000%26WhatEndPrice%3D30000000%26WhatStartBed%3D%26WhatStartBath%3D0%26DaysAgo%3D%26WhatStartIntArea%3D%26WhatSortDirection1%3DDESC%26start%3D0%26WhatNumber%3D10
```

How can i get this to work?

Comment: You need to `urldecode` it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You firstly need to decode your url, then pass it to `parse_str`. The second parameter for `parse_str` is what will be populated with your data. So you can do the following:

```
parse_str(urldecode('type%3Dbasic%26WhatPropType%3DSingle%2BFamily%2BResidential%26WhatDistrict%255B0%255D%3DHaiku%26WhatStartPrice%3D90000%26WhatEndPrice%3D30000000%26WhatStartBed%3D%26WhatStartBath%3D0%26DaysAgo%3D%26WhatStartIntArea%3D%26WhatSortDirection1%3DDESC%26start%3D0%26WhatNumber%3D10'), $array);
var_dump($array);
```

will output

```
array(12) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(5) "basic"
  ["WhatPropType"]=>
  string(25) "Single Family Residential"
  ["WhatDistrict"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Haiku"
  }
  ["WhatStartPrice"]=>
  string(5) "90000"
  ["WhatEndPrice"]=>
  string(8) "30000000"
  ["WhatStartBed"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WhatStartBath"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["DaysAgo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WhatStartIntArea"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WhatSortDirection1"]=>
  string(4) "DESC"
  ["start"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["WhatNumber"]=>
  string(2) "10"
}
```

Comment: urldecode is not working because it has no effect on (%5B0%5D)

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza, works fine for me. The `var_dump` is copy and pasted.

Comment: An old answer, but incorrect nonetheless. You end up with characters you don't want to escape. Cosider the query `q=a%2Bb%26c%3Dd`, which reads as "q=a+b&c=d" (decoded). Applying `parse_str(urldecode("q=a%2Bb%26c%3Dd"), $queryArray);` will simply yield the array "["q" => "a b", "c" => "d"]", which is massively flawed! You end up escaping many different break point characters, including "&", "=" and "+".

Answer (score 1):

```
parse_str(urldecode($yourString));
```

Answer (score 0):

as the same as our friends say decode the string

```
parse_str(urldecode('type%3Dbasic%26WhatPropType%3DSingle%2BFamily%2BResidential%26WhatDistrict%255B0%255D%3DHaiku%26WhatStartPrice%3D90000%26WhatEndPrice%3D30000000%26WhatStartBed%3D%26WhatStartBath%3D0%26DaysAgo%3D%26WhatStartIntArea%3D%26WhatSortDirection1%3DDESC%26start%3D0%26WhatNumber%3D10'), $array);
```

and get value like this

```
$array['type']  //out put "basic"
```